# Error switching into Development Mode in looker

Tags: looker

I am failing to switch to developer mode in looker.
My user has the developer access.
When I am trying to use the toggle I receive this error:

```
Error switching into Development Mode
```

I could not find any documentation for it, just other people reporting the same issue without any answer.
Did anyone encounter the issue before?

Answer (score -1):

Use the Looker API "Update User" method ([using Looker API explorer)](https://cloud.google.com/looker/docs/api-explorer#installing_the_api_explorer) and force the setting "models_dir_validated" to true. Once this got changed the user should be able to switch to development mode